# Javascript for scrolling to the top of selected panel in customised accordion

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, accordion

I have a large accordion with a vertical scroll bar.  I need a javascript to smoothly scroll the selected panel and its contents to the top of the accordion when a user clicks on it. Click on Panel 1 and then on Panel 2.  Panel 2 displays its contents midway.

I have seen several answers related to jQuery ui accordions and plugins in this website and on jsfiddle.net but the structure of my accordion isn't similar to the one in jQuery.
This is my first website and I am new to javascript and jQuery.

I have a javascript that works fine with the sliding feature and would very much like to keep it.  I prefer not to use any jQuery plugin until I learn how to do so with confidence.
Could someone please be kind enough to modify my javascript to accomodate the scrolling function?  Have tried reading many stuff such as getting the panel's content height and using a scroll to function etc. but after three long days I am still struggling to put together a script that works.  Please find attached my html and javascript code.
Thank you very much for any help and assistance.

```
enter code here
```

```js
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordian h3").click(function() {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#description {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#accordian {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #006F70;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px 16px 0 16px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="accordianFABtest-GS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="description">
    <div id="accordian">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 1</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 2</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 3</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 4</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="accordian1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for looking at my code.  What I hoped to achieve was when a user clicked on Panel 2, the script should collapse Panel 1 contents (if it is opened) and scroll the top Panel 1 header out of the way i.e. push it above and bring Panel 2 header to the top of the accordion box and display its contents.  I want the entire height of the accordion to be 400px. A effect similar to that described in http://www.stampede-design.com/blog/demo/shaiful/large-accordion/large-accordion-fix.html. My apologies for not making myself clear.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your css and set the min-height for your panel content. please see the code snippet below. I hope this helps!

```js
/*jQuery time*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#accordian h3").click(function() {
    //slide up all the link lists
    $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
    //slide down the link list below the h3 clicked - only if its closed
    if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
      $(this).next().slideDown();
    }
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#description {
  position: relative;
  top: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#accordian {
  font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #006F70;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
}
// added line
#accordian ul li ul{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="accordianFABtest-GS.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="description">
    <div id="accordian">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 1</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 1</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 2</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 2</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 3</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 3</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <h3>Panel 4</h3>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Content 4</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="accordian1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```